# show live video in a web application

Tags: java, web, xuggler

I wish to show live video in a java-web application. For this I found that xuggler(java library) is capable of doing that. But I didn't get code to how to implement it.
I have done some tutorials with xuggler like capturing frames from a video. But not much familiar with xuggler. Please help.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does 'java-web application' mean java applet?

Comment: not exactly, it will be a struts/spring based java-web application with jsp/jsf. But it is ok to support applet also.

Comment: I won't help you a lot but I found that you can use VLC player. On this site http://www.videolan.org/doc/play-howto/en/ch04.html you will find how to "read an HTTP stream inside the web page".

Comment: Embedding applet in jsp is doable and I have done it before. I am not sure about javascript. Because I want to capture stills from the live video. Hope you understand.